# Android Crash During Register Push Notifications

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I am using **gcm.jar** for Push Notifications. When I start my app I am trying to register Push notifications but it always crashed.

```
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774): BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774): java.lang.RuntimeException: BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at android.content.BroadcastReceiver.checkSynchronousHint(BroadcastReceiver.java:783)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at android.content.BroadcastReceiver.setResult(BroadcastReceiver.java:658)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GCMBroadcastReceiver.java:56)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2394)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:145)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
06-04 10:08:32.479: E/BroadcastReceiver(26774):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And my Menifest.xml is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.app.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.app.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />


    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.app.example" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.app.example.GCMIntentService" />
```

My BroadcastReciever Code is below

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService ";

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()
            .putString("REGISTRATION_KEY", registrationId).commit();
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    // Debuger.e(TAG, "Device unregistered");
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
            handleMessage(context, intent);
}

@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
}

@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    // log message
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Do whatever you want with the message
    String order_ID = intent.getStringExtra("order_id");
    String status_ID = intent.getStringExtra("status_id");
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    if (!message.equals("")) {
        if (order_ID != null && status_ID != null & !status_ID.equals("4")) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("fromGetItem", 2);
            mainIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivity.class);
            mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
        generateNotification(context, message, mainIntent);
    } 
}

private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message,
        Intent notificationIntent) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
}
```

How can I fix this crash?

Comment: Could you post your broadcast receiver code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are getting and process your messages

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        handleMessage(context, intent);
}
```

When App send request to **google** for registration of device I don't know very well but some times **google** returns message so if you are parsing your messages and **Intent** don't get your Bundle and it gives back **null** so App crash. 
You can try with below code may be it helps.

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Bundle[{CMD=RST_FULL, from=google.com/iid}]
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        if (!bundle.containsKey("CMD")) {
            handleMessage(context, intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please debug and get your message when its getting message.

Answer (score 0):

If you have method: `setResultCode()`, than delete it.

Comment: No i have not method: setResultCode()

Comment: I have the same problem and no setResultCode().